# Is my proof of $1+1=2$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, peano-axioms, formal-proofs

Here is the proof:

Note: I will denote the successor of a natural number $n$ by $(n++)$

If one assumes the Peano axioms then they may define addition as follows:

$0+m:=m$

$(n++)+m=(n+m)(++)$

$\forall n,m\in\mathbb{N}$

Using these definitions, here is a simple proof of $1+1=2$

$1+1$

$=(0++)+1$

$=(0+1)(++)$

$=(1++)$

$=2$

$\therefore{1+1=2}$

$Q.E.D$

Comment: That's the usual proof indeed!

Comment: No that it matters for your proof, but the usual definition of sum is given by 1) $m+0:=m$ and 2) $m+(n++):=(m+n)++$

Comment: @AlvinL 2 is defined to be the successor of one that is 1++ with this notation. and addition is defined inductively as follows:
0 + n = n and  (m++)+ n = (m+n)++

Comment: Some people think it takes 500 pages to prove this though :)

Comment: @Aria I'm sure they are not like famous mathematicians or something.

Comment: @Ennar Definitely. It's just a common misconception that I've heard from several people, because Bertrand Russell proves it after a thousand pages in his book.

Comment: @Aria, well, my joke was about Russell and Whitehead which I thought you were joking about as well :D

Comment: @Ennar oh gotcha 

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the proof is correct. I think the only way to sort of "improve" it would be to include right away in the definitions that $1$ is the successor of $0$ and $2$ is the successor of $1$.